# Appium inspector keep crashing while recording

Tags: ios, selenium, ios-simulator, appium

I am using Appium inspector (latest build, 0.16). It loads my simulator, runs the app and when I tries to record a button click it crashes immediately.

My Appium configurations:

[image]

Now as soon as I try recording an action (tap in a button), the inspector crashes:

[image]

The log output for this operation is:

```
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/20f2371d-a72a-4aff-a5e8-bb3005c403a5/element

POST /wd/hub/session/20f2371d-a72a-4aff-a5e8-bb3005c403a5/element 404 1ms - 53b

debug: Request received with params: {"using":"name","value":"Init BC"}
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/20f2371d-a72a-4aff-a5e8-bb3005c403a5/element/(null)/click
debug: Request received with params: {}

POST /wd/hub/session/20f2371d-a72a-4aff-a5e8-bb3005c403a5/element/(null)/click 404 0ms - 53b

debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/20f2371d-a72a-4aff-a5e8-bb3005c403a5/source
debug: Request received with params: {}
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/20f2371d-a72a-4aff-a5e8-bb3005c403a5/screenshot
debug: Request received with params: {}
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/20f2371d-a72a-4aff-a5e8-bb3005c403a5/window_handles
debug: Request received with params: {}

GET /wd/hub/session/20f2371d-a72a-4aff-a5e8-bb3005c403a5/source 404 1ms - 53b
GET /wd/hub/session/20f2371d-a72a-4aff-a5e8-bb3005c403a5/screenshot 404 1ms - 53b
GET /wd/hub/session/20f2371d-a72a-4aff-a5e8-bb3005c403a5/window_handles 404 0ms - 53b

debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/status

info: Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"0.16.0","revision":"292d265edd9c7aaf96f165009285c814b218363d"}}}

debug: Request received with params: {}

GET /wd/hub/status 200 1ms - 144b

info: Didn't get a new command in 60 secs, shutting down...

info: Trying to stop appium but there's no session, doing nothing
info: We shut down because no new commands came in

debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/status

info: Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"0.16.0","revision":"292d265edd9c7aaf96f165009285c814b218363d"}}}

debug: Request received with params: {}

GET /wd/hub/status 200 1ms - 144b
```

**EDIT**:
Please note those two lines on logs:

- POST /wd/hub/session/20f2371d-a72a-4aff-a5e8-bb3005c403a5/element 404 1ms - 53b
- POST /wd/hub/session/20f2371d-a72a-4aff-a5e8-bb3005c403a5/element/(null)/click 404 0ms - 53b

I guess this caused of the crash. The question is why??

Comment: have you fixed the issue? i got same issue and not able to record now appium inspector launch my application on device quit and appium server stopped

Comment: This seems to work much better on newly released Appium 1.0.0. Give it a try...